# Unable to use StatelessComponent in typescript using react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, typescript2.0, react-native-button

I am trying to extend `Button` component of [react-native-button](https://github.com/ide/react-native-button) library.

The class using the extended component:

```
import { DefaultButton } from "../../support/ui/DefaultButton";

...

render() {
    const loginProps = {
            title: "login",
            style: {backgroundColor: DefaultTheme.blueColor},
            containerStyle: {backgroundColor: DefaultTheme.blueColor, flex: 0.5}
        };

    return (<DefaultButton {...loginProps}>test</DefaultButton>);
}
```

My extended component class, `DefaultButton.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, IButtonProperties } from 'react-native-button';


// default button component using stateless functional component
// https://medium.com/@housecor/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc#.vizff8ap4
// http://donormal.com/writing/stateless-components-in-react-typescript/
const DefaultButton : React.StatelessComponent<IButtonProperties> = (props: IButtonProperties) => (
    <Button style={props.style}
            containerStyle={props.containerStyle}>
        {props.children}
    </Button>
)

export { DefaultButton };
```

But the above code would result in:

[image]

Any clues on what is going wrong with my code?

P.S. here is the library version I am using:

```
"react-native": "0.39.2",
"react-native-button": "1.7.1",
"typescript": "2.1.4",
```

Comment: Would you provide how to import `DefaultButton`? And in TypeScript you can just do `export const DefaultButton...`

Answer (score 0):

You should import Button like:

import  Button from 'react-native-button';

Answer (score -1):

You should pass "title" props for Button because in [new react native version](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html) it updated. You should create component like this in your DefaultButton component class:

```
const DefaultButton : React.StatelessComponent<IButtonProperties> = (props: IButtonProperties) => (

<Button title='Button_Title'
        style={props.style}
        containerStyle={props.containerStyle}>
        {props.children}
</Button>
)
```

if you are creating your own button then you can write as old style in any component like:

```
<DefaultButton>
  Button_Title
</DefaultButton>
```

But you should access the child component from DefaultButton. Thanks!

Comment: But I am using react native version 0.39.2.

Comment: I am not using react native's `Button` component. I am using https://github.com/ide/react-native-button instead.

Comment: Hey, you should use Button without braces around it on import as:

 `import Button from 'react-native-button'`

This is working for me. Thanks!

Comment: The reason behind it is, Button is a component class inside react-native-button library and we can not access component created as class with {} braces. Thanks!